# JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, tsx

I get this error when using "Cropper" from the react-easy-crop lib, I've tried a few things that I found on forums such as adding @types/react, importing * as React from "react" but nothing seems to work.

Here's the code giving me trouble:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Cropper from "react-easy-crop";

export default function CropperPage({action , valuePro}: any) {
   return (
     <Cropper //  <-- This is giving me the error
        cropShape= "round"
        disableAutomaticStylesInjection="true"
        image={image}
        crop={crop}
        zoom={zoom}
        aspect={1}
        onCropChange={setCrop}
        onZoomChange={setZoom}
        onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
    />
   );
}
```

The whole error message is:

> Blockquote
> JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)
> 'Cropper' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its instance type 'Cropper' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'Cropper' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refsts(2786)
> (alias) class Cropper
> import Cropper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I actually ran into this recently and after failing to find an answer here, was able to use typescript's `traceResolution` feature to discover: typescript was resolving `import "react"` to `node_modules/react/index.js` instead of `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`.  Some changes to my tsconfig.json were able to resolve this - I had `node_modules/*` in one of my `paths` matches, and had to add `node_modules/@types/*` to also get it to look for `@types/` packages.

So I'd recommend using traceResolution (either as a tsc flag, or a tsconfig.json field) and seeing if react is mis-resolving, and if it is the case, focus on fixing that; it could be the same issue where node_modules/react gets found instead of node_modules/@types/react though the traceResolution output will have a clear final word on that.

Comment: How should I change my tsconfig.json in order to force typescript to look into the @types directory first?

Comment: something like `"paths": {"*": ["node_modules/@types/*", "node_modules/*"], ...}`.  you could also specifically override resolution of `react` like `"paths": {"react": ["node_modules/@types/react"]} - but if react has this issue, you've probably misconfigured such that any library that depends on types from an @types/ package will also have this issue and I figure it's better to solve the general case.

Answer (score 91):

I had the same error with `<Text></Text>` and it was because I had not imported the component.

Comment: Wow. Yeah. Autoimport backstabbed me my importing an equally named thing from a different package.

Comment: sometimes the problem is just me forgetting to import it :/

Comment: There should be a much better error message by react. The current error is misleading!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where today this error occured on the same project that was running perfectly fine the other day. After a lot of trial and error I ended up deleting my node_modules folder and recreating it with a `npm install`. Then it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same issue when I am using antd `Option` component, my code like this:

```
const renderPhotoTypeImpl = () => {
    const photoList: JSX.Element[] = [];
    if (photoType && photoType.length > 0) {
    photoType.forEach(item => {
        photoList.push(
        <Option value={item} label={item}>
            <Space>
                <span role="img" aria-label="China">
                </span>
                Dog
            </Space>
        </Option>);
    });
    }
    return (<div></div>);
}
```

just add the `Option` define like this will fixed this issue:

```
const { Option } = Select;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vscode, restarting vscode resolve the issue

Answer (score -3):

```
import Cropper from "react-easy-crop";

interface CropperFix extends React.Component {}

const Cropped = (Cropper as any) as {
    new(): CropperFix;
};

const props: any = {
    cropShape: "round",
    disableAutomaticStylesInjection: true,
    image,
    crop,
    zoom,
    aspect: 1,
    onCropChange: setCrop,
    onZoomChange: setZoom,
    onCropComplete: onCropComplete,
}

...

<Cropped ...props/>
```

Probably ugly but works

Comment: any clarifications? what it does and how to fix similiar problem?

Comment: Please add a brief explanation why this works

Comment: this solution really just works around the type system rather than doing anything right - the casts to `any` are what make it particularly ugly and destroy all type safety.